# Autopy mouse automation process

Tags: autopy

I'm trying to automate a process in which my mouse/cursor moves in a loop and writes a value (which is in this loop).

```
autopy.mouse.move(800,350) 
time.sleep(0.75)
autopy.mouse.click(LEFT_BUTTON)
autopy.mouse.click(LEFT_BUTTON)
time.sleep(2.0)
autopy.key.type_string("100")
time.sleep(1.0)
```

Is there a way in which I can use "autopy.key.type_string("100")" to change nos in this loop.

For eg. 100, 200, 300 . . . .1000 and so on.

Since, autopy only takes strings, I'm unable to do so. Please, let me know, if you've an idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=100
autopy.key.type_string('%d'%a)
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0,1000,100):
    autopy.mouse.smooth_move(800,350) 
    time.sleep(0.75)
    autopy.mouse.click()
    autopy.mouse.click()
    time.sleep(2.0)
    autopy.key.type_string(str(i))
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

`smooth_move` for slow move